# What are "siblings" of .json files?

Tags: json

I was reading through the documentation for Bower [here](http://bower.io/) and I read this line: "The .bowerrc file should be a sibling of your project's bower.json." What does that mean exactly? Searching Google returned questions of people asking how to find siblings, but not what they actually are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siblings share the same parent, so it means they should both be in the same folder.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was probably something as simple as that.